# What Happens if a .h Filename Doesn't Match the @interface Name iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, interface

If I have `Person.h` but have the following code

```
@interface ClassOne

@end
```

does anything bad happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you should `#include` (or better `#import`) `Person.h` to access `ClassOne` definition.

Answer (score 3):

No file name and name of class(classes) in it must not necessarily relate to each other (while you import correct header where needed) .

Although of course your project will be easier to work with and support if they do.